# Filter a haskell data type

Tags: haskell, types, filter

This is my code I have so far:

```
    arcticMonkeysAreTheBest = Review    "Arctic Monkeys"
                                5
                                arcticMonkeys2012
                                "18/08/2013"
                                "België"
                                Festival
                                ["I bet you look good on the dancefloor", "When the sun goes down", "Still take you home"]

    arcticMonkeysRock = Review  "Artic Monkeys"
                        5
                        arcticMonkeys2013
                        "17/08/2013"
                        "België"
                        Zaal
                        ["R U Mine?", "Arabella", "Why'd you only call me when you're high?"]

    reviews = [arcticMonkeysAreTheBest, arcticMonkeysRock]
```

Now my question is: How can I filter the reviews with `Location = Zaal` for example?

Is it also possible to filter with two criteria? For example where `artist= Arctic Monkeys` and where `Location = Zaal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably define your review type to be

```
data Review = Review
  { reviewBand     :: String
  , reviewStars    :: Integer
  , reviewTour     :: Tour
  , reviewData     :: String
  , reviewCountry  :: String
  , reviewLocation :: Location
  , reviewSongs    :: [String]
  } deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

and your `Location` type to be

```
data Location = Festival | Zaal deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

You can then easily do

```
>> filter (\review -> reviewLocation review == Zaal) reviews
```

or even more concisely

```
>> filter ((== Zaal) . reviewLocation) reviews
```

**Edit**

If you want this as a function, it is as simple as defining

```
filterByLocation :: Location -> [Review] -> [Review]
filterByLocation location = filter (\r -> reviewLocation r == location)
```

Comment: Thank you verry much, this works perfect!

Comment: Is it also possible to put that in a function? That would be even more usefull that always use the ghci.

Comment: @brampieOO I edited to include that information.

Comment: The code compiles but when I run the function filterByLocation I get this error: No instance for (Show ([Review] -> [Review])) arising from a use of `print' and the possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show([Review] -> [Review])) In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: You need to run it like `filterByLocation Zaal reviews`. If you just type `filterByLocation Zaal` than you get a function of type `[Review] -> [Review]` which can't be printed to the screen. That's what the error "`no instance for Show ([Review] -> [Review]) ...`" is telling you.

Comment: Is it also possible to filter with two criteria? for example where the Location = Zaal and where artist = Arctic Monkeys?

Comment: @brampieOO Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Review` type is defined like

```
data Review = Review String Int String String String String [String]
```

then you can write a function to match a `Review` based on a given location:

```
findByLocation loc (Review _ _ _ _ _ location _) | loc == location = True
findByLocation _ _ = False
```

Then you can find reviews with the location `Zaal` with

```
let matches = filter (findByLocation Zaal) reviews
```

Comment: Now my code compiles, but when I try to run that filter, it can't find anything although there is a Review with the location Zaal.

My Review is defined like this:

data Review = Review String Integer Tour String String Locatie [String]

Maybe that is why I can't find anything