# Filter in List with custom data types

Tags: haskell

I have just started using Haskell. And I am using it for log parsing, and I am trying to filter the log. but getting error related to TypeMismatch.

Here is what I did.

**my data types**

```
data LogExStack = LogExStack {
    methodName :: String,
    className :: String,
    extraInfo :: String
} | List [LogExStack] deriving Show
data LogException = LogException {
    exFirstLine :: LogExFirstLine,
    exMessage :: LogExMessage,
    exStackTrace :: LogExStack
} deriving Show
```

I want to have the filter on `LogExStack` type data.
and my function for creating that list looks something like this

```
exceptionStackTraceParser :: Parser LogExStack
exceptionStackTraceParser =
    M.liftM List $ sepBy exceptionParser newLinesTabEx


exceptionParser :: Parser LogExStack
exceptionParser =
    do
        string "at"
        method <- many (noneOf "(")
        string "("
        className <- many (noneOf ")")
        string ")"
        extraInfo <- many (noneOf "\n")
        string "\n"
        return $ LogExStack method className extraInfo
```

till now it's fine, but when I tried to use the list for filter it didn't work. I wanted to have filter on the methodName from LogExStack list.

here is my function for that

```
filterStackTrace :: [LogExStack] -> [LogExStack]
filterStackTrace  = filter (\r -> methodName r == "com.xyz.abc")
```

I also tried without [] but it failed as well. can anyone help me with this.
I took the reference for my implementation from here

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing

[Filter a haskell data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653830/filter-a-haskell-data-type)

can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

**EDIT**

here is the changes I make after reading Arnon post

```
exceptionStackTraceParser :: Parser [LogExStack]
exceptionStackTraceParser =
    sepBy exceptionParser newLinesTabEx
```

here is how I am calling filter

```
parseExpr :: Parser LogException
parseExpr = 
    do
        fstLine <- exceptionFirstLineParser
        msgLine <- exceptionMessageParser
        stackTrace <- exceptionStackTraceParser
        list <- filterStackTrace stackTrace
        return $ LogException fstLine msgLine list
```

and here is my exception

```
H:\>ghc --make -O logparser.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( logparser.hs, logparser.o )

logparser.hs:69:25:
    Couldn't match type `[]'
                  with `Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                          String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity'
    Expected type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                     String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity LogExStack
      Actual type: [LogExStack]
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: list <- filterStackTrace stackTrace
    In the expression:
      do { fstLine <- exceptionFirstLineParser;
           msgLine <- exceptionMessageParser;
           stackTrace <- exceptionStackTraceParser;
           list <- filterStackTrace stackTrace;
           .... }
```

**EDIT2**
Got it I was calling the list filter from wrong place somehow I can not call from the parseExpr function, because I don't know somehow it thinks called function from there must be Parsec type.

I don't know why? can anybody help me understand that?

Comment: Do you have the exact error message? It doesn't look like a Type Mismatch.

Comment: An unrelated error is that LogExStack may not have a methodName. You would want to deal with that.

Comment: @PyRulez I have added the error details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume that you are calling the filter wrong:

You defined your own data type `List [LogExStack]`, but your `filterStackTrace` accepts just `[LogExStack]`. You would therefore need to have to 'extract' the actual list from the `List` constructor before calling `filterStackTrace`, perhaps by pattern matching it in the `filterStackTrace` clause:

```
filterStackTrace :: LogExStack -> LogExStack
filterStackTrace  (List l) = List $ filter (\r -> methodName r == "com.xyz.abc") l
```

Edit:
On second thought actually, defining your own list type here is a bit weird.
Why not just have the data type as

```
data LogExStack = LogExStack {
    methodName :: String,
    className :: String,
    extraInfo :: String
} deriving Show
```

Then altering the parser to return the proper list version of `LogExStack`

```
exceptionStackTraceParser :: Parser [LogExStack]
exceptionStackTraceParser =
    sepBy exceptionParser newLinesTabEx
```

And then calling the `filterStackTrace` as you wrote it originally?

Edit 2, as a response:
You are missing the call to `parse`.
This simple program worked for me:

```
module Main where
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

data LogExStack = LogExStack {
    methodName :: String,
    className :: String,
    extraInfo :: String
} deriving Show

exceptionParser :: Parser LogExStack
exceptionParser =
    do
        _ <- string "at"
        method <- many (noneOf "(")
        _ <- string "("
        className' <- many (noneOf ")")
        _ <- string ")"
        extraInfo' <- many (noneOf "\n")
        _ <- string "\n"
        return $ LogExStack method className' extraInfo'

exceptionStackTraceParser :: Parser [LogExStack]
exceptionStackTraceParser =
    exceptionParser `sepBy` newLinesTabEx
  where
    newLinesTabEx = oneOf "\t\r\n"

main :: IO ()
main = do
     case (parse exceptionParser "example" "bla bla bla bla") of
      Left err -> print $ "Error: " ++ show err
      Right xs -> print xs
```

Comment: I have made the changes as you have said but its still showing Type error, I have edited my question

Comment: @NixitPatel I updated my answer, have a look at that example